# Is there multiple contributor integration in Monaco Editor built in?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm working on a project that allows two people to work on the same code from different computers. I would like to use Monaco because it's so bare bones. I imagine I can use something like socket.io to integrate this functionality. I was curious if it's already available in monaco. Basically, the same page is accessed by multiple people, whatever they type shows up for all viewers of the page. This is the same functionality as codeshare.io which is what I'm trying to emulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and I am quite sure that wont happen since it is mainly from VS Code - client site editor, and the Monaco is used on Git centric site like Visual Studio Team Service (but also on Azure - but still). Also I reckon its a fairly big task to accomplish in the right way.

I know prosemirror.net has it - but that is not a code editor; Although it has a sample that embeds CodeMirror in it.